# msaccess adodb insert statement

Tags: ms-access, parameters, adodb

I have this code where I get variables from a table and it want to insert them into a new table.
I keep getting errors on the insert statement, but I can't seem to figure out why.
I only get an error Syntax error in insert into statement, nothing more.

'ADO

```
Sub ProcessRecords()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DateTimeData As String
    Dim CallerNumberData As String
    Dim CalledNumberData As String
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & CurrentDb.Name
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Clean_Log_Telefooncentrale;"
    Set rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)
    
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If InStr(rs("Param"), "Date event") > 0 Then
            DateTimeData = rs("ParamData")
        ElseIf InStr(rs("Param"), "Calling party number") > 0 Then
            CallerNumberData = rs("ParamData")
        ElseIf InStr(rs("Param"), "Called party number") > 0 Then
            CalledNumberData = rs("ParamData")
            
        ' Debug output
        Debug.Print "DateTimeData: " & DateTimeData
        Debug.Print "CallerNumberData: " & CallerNumberData
        Debug.Print "CalledNumberData: " & CalledNumberData
            
            ' Insert the data into the new table if all values are present
            If DateTimeData <> "" And CallerNumberData <> "" And CalledNumberData <> "" Then
                conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Tbl_Telefooncentrale (DateTime, CallerNumber, CalledNumber) VALUES ('" & DateTimeData & "', '" & CallerNumberData & "', '" & CalledNumberData & "')"
            End If
            
            ' Reset variables
            DateTimeData = ""
            CallerNumberData = ""
            CalledNumberData = ""
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried DAO, but I am having issues with the library, so that is not an option.
I would like to keep ADODB, I also tried to put the params seperatly, but I am keep having issues with the insert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` is a reserved word and your logic doesn't seem right, so try:

```vb
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If InStr(rs("Param"), "Date event") > 0 Then
            DateTimeData = rs("ParamData")
        ElseIf InStr(rs("Param"), "Calling party number") > 0 Then
            CallerNumberData = rs("ParamData")
        ElseIf InStr(rs("Param"), "Called party number") > 0 Then
            CalledNumberData = rs("ParamData")
        End If
            
        ' Debug output
        Debug.Print "DateTimeData: " & DateTimeData
        Debug.Print "CallerNumberData: " & CallerNumberData
        Debug.Print "CalledNumberData: " & CalledNumberData
            
        ' Insert the data into the new table if all values are present
        If DateTimeData <> "" And CallerNumberData <> "" And CalledNumberData <> "" Then
            conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Tbl_Telefooncentrale ([DateTime], CallerNumber, CalledNumber) VALUES ('" & DateTimeData & "', '" & CallerNumberData & "', '" & CalledNumberData & "')"
            
            ' Reset variables
            DateTimeData = ""
            CallerNumberData = ""
            CalledNumberData = ""
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```